# ANR on Surface.nativeLockCanvas on some devices

Tags: android, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I need to draw over `SurfaceView` on events from accelerometer.
I create callback for checking that surface ready.

```
overlaySurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.overlay_surface);
overlaySurfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
overlayHolder = overlaySurfaceView.getHolder();
overlayHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
overlayHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        overlayReady = true;
        Log.d(TAG, "SET overlayReady = true");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        overlayReady = false;
        Log.d(TAG, "SET overlayReady = false");
    }
});
```

In sensor listener I lock canvas and draw somethng

```
private final SensorEventListener orientationListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged: overlayReady = " + overlayReady);

        if (!overlayReady)
            return;

        if (overlayHolder == null || overlayHolder.isCreating() || !overlayHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            return;
        }

        Canvas canvas = overlayHolder.lockCanvas();
        if (canvas == null) {
            return;
        }

        canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        // Some drawing
        overlayHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
};
```

But from one client with `Transformer Pad (TF103CG) (K018)` I get ANR with description *Waiting because the touched window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.*

```
----- pid 10710 at 2016-03-02 17:25:43 -----
Cmd line: com.####.#####
JNI: CheckJNI is off; workarounds are off; pins=0; globals=295
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x430f7340 self=0x430e4620
  | sysTid=10710 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073954880
  | state=S schedstat=( 11049431919 2136334229 17921 ) utm=902 stm=202 core=1
  (native backtrace unavailable)
  at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:243)
  at android.view.SurfaceView$4.internalLockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:822)
  at android.view.SurfaceView$4.lockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:790)
  at com.####.#####.CustomCameraActivity$6.onSensorChanged(CustomCameraActivity.java:342)
  at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:418)
```

Full text of ANR log [here.](http://pastebin.com/N5iUKGZu)

Where there can be a problem?

Comment: Include the full ANR trace. If this thread is getting stuck because it's waiting on some other thread, then it's important to know where the other threads are.

Comment: Add a link to full log http://pastebin.com/N5iUKGZu

Comment: I don't see a conflict in the stack trace. What version of Android is this? I wasn't able to make the line numbers match up with recent AOSP SurfaceView (e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-mr2-release/core/java/android/view/SurfaceView.java), so it's possible there's some custom code for this device that is at fault.

Comment: Android 4.4.2 on this device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solutuion I create another thread and move code from `onSensorChanged` to it.
In a thread I draw on canvas and sleep 100ms. In `onSensorChanged` now I only save sensor values.